# Limit in measure of sequence of integrable function is integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space.

$\{f_n\} $ is sequence of integrable function converge in measure to a function $f $.

$f$ is a integeable function?

Answer (score 0):

For a counterexample take $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)=([0,1],\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]},\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $f_n(x)=x^{-1}\wedge n$.